# Sound energy transformation

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation, acoustics, dissipation

What does sound energy transforms into? Energy can neither be created nor be destroyed. So what does sound energy change into?

Answer (score 0):

Sound is just pressure waves propagating back and forth, so kinetic energy, when it gets absorbed by an object it just jiggles its constituent particles, so basically it stays kinetic energy; macroscopically you could say it turns into thermal energy since the thermal energy of an object is the total kinetic energy of its constituent atoms/molecules.